# How to run a Tkinter program without opening a terminal

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal, window

When I run my Tkinter application, a command line/terminal opens. How can I run my application without it invoking a command line/terminal session?

Comment: do you mean in Microsoft Windows - running by clicking script icon ? There should be `pyw.exe` to run without `terminal`.

Answer (score 3):

Save your file with ".pyw" extension instead of ".py".